# How to ignore whitespaces on solr query

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have the name `Audioslave` indexed on Solr and I want to match that document to the query string `Audio Slave`.

I have the following rule configured:

```
<fieldType name="text_filter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And a field using it:

```
<field name="artist_name_filter"  type="text_filter"  multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

When using Solr analysis tool everything looks good.

The Query part is the following:

- The KeywordTokenizerFactory generates `Audio Slave`,
- Then the WordDelimiterFilterFactory splits it into `Audio Slave`, `Audio`, `AudioSlave` and `Slave` (lets just use the 3rd column (`AudioSlave`) from here.
- The TrimFilterFactory keeps it as `AudioSlave`
- Finally the LowerCaseFilterFactory change it to `audioslave`

On the other hand, the index part is:

- The KeywordTokenizerFactory generates `Audioslave`,
- Then the WordDelimiterFilterFactory and TrimFilterFactory keeps it as `Audioslave`
- Finally the LowerCaseFilterFactory change it to `audioslave`

So both fields should match, but the query returns no results:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/search_api/select?defType=edismax&fq=type:Artist&q=Audio%20slave&qf=artist_name_filter&wt=json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't analysis, it's QueryParser syntax.  Spaces are used to separate query clauses, and that isn't affected by the analyzer.  When you have `q=Audio slave`, it applies query syntax rules first, and separates it into clauses "Audio" and "slave", and then analyzes each clause separately.

Escaping the space should do the job, I believe:  `q=Audio\ slave`

A phrase query here seems like it ought to work, such as `q="Audio slave"`, but it doesn't.  It generates something like:  `"(audio slave audio audioslave) slave"` for me, which is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` as a tokenizer for your index part.
Here the `KeywordTokenizerFactory` keeps the text as it is...it won't create any tokens.

Replace the same with `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`.
`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` will create tokens at space.

Comment: Their analysis is using `WordDelimiterFilter` to create separate tokens, instead of the Tokenizer.